# C# OPC-UA Client: Get ComplexType of Node an instantiate object to write

Tags: c#, opc-ua

I use the netStandard library of the OPC Foundation to connect to an OPC-UA server with complex types.

With the `ComplexTypeSystem` I can load the types as `RuntimeTypes` and when I read a node with a complex type I get an object of this type and can work with it, e.g. get the properties by reflection, display them etc.

But how can I create an instance of a complex type of a node to write to that node? The only way I could find was to read the value first and reuse that object instance, but that leads to a lot of unnecessary reads....